# How to turn an Observable of a type into an Observable of another type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, operators

I have an Angular application that uses NGRX to manage the application state.
I have a selector that return me an Observable.

```
export const mySelector = createSelector(state, (state: IState) => state.field.array);
```

The Observable returned has this format: `{name:string; age:number}[]`

What I need to do is to turn that data format in another data format, for example `{firt-name:string}`.
I can't understand what operator should I use.

My goal is to assign the new data to a variable, inside the subscribe, somethig like this:

```
myVariable: {firt-name:string};

this.store.pipe(select(mySelector))
         .pipe(//here I should transform the data format)
         .subscribe(result => {myVariable = result})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `map`:

```
function mapper(data: { name: string; age: number }[]) {
  return data.map(({ name, age }) => ({
    "first-name": name,
    age
  }));
}

this.store
  .pipe(
    select(mySelector),
    map(mapper)
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    myVariable = result;
  });
```

or perform that transformation in your selector:

```
function mapper(data: { name: string; age: number }[]) {
  return data.map(({ name, age }) => ({
    "first-name": name,
    age
  }));
}

this.store
  .pipe(
    select(
      pipe(
        mySelector,
        mapper
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    myVariable = result;
  });
```